# Calculate minimum total value and delete all other rows from Table

Tags: sql-server

Here's my table.

```
Table MyTable
-------------
ID  Distance1   Cost1               Distance2   Cost2       Distance3   Cost3
1   711.9       6196.90432379846    NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2   672.4       7316.33             NULL        NULL        103.5       900.941 8217.271
3   787.7       8570.9              252         2193.59     NULL        NULL
```

What I want is, find out row which has minimum total (Cost1+Cost2+Cost3). Keep that row and delete everything else.

So far I have achieved this. This gives me row which has minimum total value.

```
select TOP 1 *, ISNULL(Cost1, 0 )+ISNULL(Cost2, 0 )+ISNULL(Cost3, 0 ) as TotalCost from MyTable order by TotalCost
```

I also want to delete other rows. Is there anyway I can do this in one statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CTE` and `Row_Number` window function to delete

```
;with cte as
(
select Row_number()over(order by ISNULL(Cost1, 0)+ISNULL(Cost2, 0 )+ISNULL(Cost3, 0)) rn,* 
from MyTable
)
Delete from cte where rn > 1
```